# Http request to a website to get the content of a specific html element

Tags: javascript, html, http, web-scraping

I am building a site to help students schedule their university courses. It will include things like days, times, professor, etc. I want to fetch the "rating" of professors off www.ratemyprofessors.com and have it show on my site. For example, at https://www.ratemyprofessors.com/ShowRatings.jsp?tid=1230754 you can see Michael has a rating of 4.6. I want to request that data and have it show on the site. I can't scrape it beforehand as their ratings change and I want it to show their current rating. Am I able to do this with an XmlHttpRequest? How would I do that? I'm hoping to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser won't let http requests towards third party websites leave your webpage unless the target site allows it. This is called CORS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. While you may be lucky if that site allows (or doesn't disallow), that may change in the future, leaving you in a bind (malfuntioning feature).

Also, what you're planning to do is called web scraping, and typically it isn't favored by webmasters, so you might eventually get blocked or stumble upon a change in content markup, again leaving you in the same bind.

I would ask the owner of that site for permission and, perhaps, API access.

Otherwise, your option #1 is to try making that http-request from the browser-level script (yes, you can use ajax, XmlHttpRequest, the new fetch API, or a third-party script), which will work only if CORS isn't a problem.

Your option #2 is to make the same request from the server (so, ajax to your server app, which scrapes the remote site), and this would be the workaround for the potential CORS problem. Again, CORS is an obstacle only at the browser level, cause browsers are coded to intercept that to minimize potential harm to user's data. However, this option is subject to eventually having your server blocked from accessing the remote site, which would be done by that site's owner and by simply configuring it to not accept connections from IP addresses that they detect as belonging to your site. Pretty cool, huh?

Both of these options are further subject to the problem of dealing with content changes, which would be in hands of your post-request script, whether executing at the browser (option 1) or at the server (option 2), which could be an ongoing maintenance. Either way, craft it in such a way to treat that 3rd-party data as a nice-to-have (so, don't crash your page when fetching that other data fails).

Edit: I would have to try this to be certain, but it's something to think about: you could embed a hidden iframe in your page, targetting that remote webpage (as in your example), then parse the iframe's content once it's available. Note that this endeavor (did I spell that right) is not trivial AT ALL, and it would cost quite a chunk of development time (and it wouldn't be a task a beginner could reasonably complete, at least not quickly), and - again - I am not 100% certain that it would even be possible, as the iframe-hosting webpage may not have access to iframe's content when it'a served by a 3rd-party website. So, this would potentially be option #3, and it would be at-browser solution (so, lots of javascript), however not susceptible to CORS blocking. Phew, a lot of words, I know - but they do make sense, if you can believe me.

Hope that helps decide. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think option 2 will be my best bet as I ran into the CORS problem with option 1. Do you have a library you recommend for scraping from the server? I'm currently looking into cURL for PHP

Comment: I don't remember ever doing that extensively, and it would have been too long ago to be relevant (I think I used .Net-compatible HtmlAgilityPack to parse html after it's downloaded over http), but a quick search online yielded this tutorial, which looks promising (however, it's server-side node solution, so option 2): https://medium.com/data-scraper-tips-tricks/scraping-data-with-javascript-in-3-minutes-8a7cf8275b31

Comment: Try this for client-side "html parsing with javascript" (those are good search keywords for option 1; remember, this is a 2-step process: download html, find values of interest): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: oh, i just realized you're on php on the server. try this (option 2):  https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/. And, yes, this would be the second, post-download step mentioned in the comment above, for which you can use any http-client, including curl.